# Unable to connect to wifi networks Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

Usb Wifi dongle TP-Link TL-WN725N
driver installed: rtl8188eus (tried with rtl8188eu as well)
Linux 18.04 LTS
kernel: 4.18.0-16-generic\

Content of /etc/wpa_supplicant:

```
country=SE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="testAP"
        #psk="testPWPW"
        psk=ed05ceb1c4aa2f52b3047d87c499e53eb822cd6c0b09eae82f814c66e44a0f79
}
```

log output from command 
*sudo wpa_supplicant -iwlx7cc2c629d018 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dnl80211*

```
wlx7cc2c629d018: Trying to associate with not_revealing_this_here (SSID='testAP' freq=2457 MHz)
wlx7cc2c629d018: Associated with not_revealing_this_here
wlx7cc2c629d018: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlx7cc2c629d018: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=not_revealing_this_here reason=0 locally_generated=1
wlx7cc2c629d018: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlx7cc2c629d018: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=SE
wlx7cc2c629d018: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
wlx7cc2c629d018: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=not_revealing_this_here reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlx7cc2c629d018: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
nl80211: Was expecting local disconnect but got another disconnect event first
```

This is regardless of what network I try to connect to. 
Can anyone help me here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/linux-firmware/filelist ?

Comment: @A.B Im sorry I dont understand your comment? should I look for anythin here?

Comment: eus refers to this repo [link](https://github.com/AIRCRACK-NG/RTL8188EUS ) since it was recommended in a post for enabling ap on this interface.

Comment: Translation: did you install the package linux-firmware? If no, does installing it and rebooting make any difference?

Comment: These two resides in the /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/ folder: rtl8188eufw.bin rtl8188efw.bin. Which should be correct right? They are listed in your link as well at least And yes I´ve rebooted several times.